# Oracle ODBC Driver For Windows

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

Need your expert suggestion on the below please.

In my office we don't have a specific package for Oracle ODBC driver, what we have is either oracle 11g or other software with which the driver is included. Now we want to create a separate package for the driver itself. Once the drive is installed we would connect our excel or any office application to the DB.

Because we cant download and run the exe files directly I need to raise a service request with our software packaging team and I need to provide the link from where they can get the package. Then they can download from there and will create a installable package for the team.

I looked through google and came up with below link.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-098155.html

I am providing the OS details below, could you guys please confirm if its the right package I am referring to or I need something else.

**System Details**

Windows Edition: Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1)
System Type: 64 bit

We need to connect to an Oracle database.

Thank you for your guidance in advance.

Comment: I guess you need Oracle Instant client. Have a look at this link -   http://danielstudds.com/installing-oracle-instant-client-and-connecting-to-oracle-from-excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must download from [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows 32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

Package **instantclient-odbc-nt-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip**

I assume your Excel is 32-bit, thus you must install also the 32-bit version of Oracle. Otherwise use [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

The 64-bit Oracle ODBC does not work with 32-bit Excel! (or vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to confirm the download for an Oracle ODBC Driver for 64-bit Windows.  This isn't a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but the short answer is, **yes** that looks correct.

In my experience ODBC installation is rarely straightforward, so worst-case, you can uninstall the driver and try a different one.  For example, [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) claims to be an "**Instant Client**" including ODBC support.

With SQL Server/ODBC on Windows 7 64 bit, I had a lot of problems before I tried the 32-bit version, which worked fine.

Any further questions about setting this up might be better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).